# Word 2016: How to align equations on the = sign when equations are in a column in a table

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, equation-editor, microsoft-word-2016

So, when I have a series of equations each on their own line in "display" mode, I can usually select them all and click "align on =" which horizontally aligns all of the equations at the = sign.

I am putting my equations in a 2 column table though, so that I can add comments on my math. (E.g., "Differentiating with respect to L,"). How can I align the equations on the = sign in the right column of the table. The option is not there when I select them.

Is it just not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Align at =` option isn't available across table cells.

As a workaround, you can split your equations to three columns: the left hand side, the equals sign and right hand side. So for each equation you need to insert two equation objects, one for each side, and an `=` sign in the middle.

Here's an example table:

[image]

I've aligned the left equation to the right and the right equation to the left. I've also set the vertical alignment of all cells to Center and removed the borders.